# Java Vector - Array index out of bounds

Tags: java, vector, indexoutofboundsexception

This seems trivial, but perhaps my understanding of Vectors is not what it should be.  I'm getting **[java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 1]** on this code.  The error occurs on line 3.    Since the look is based on the size of the Vector, how can the array go out of bounds?

The method "getChangeSets()" returns a List.  The List was originally created as a Vector.

```
2   for (int i = 0; i < getChangeSets().size(); i++) {
3       ChangeSet currentChangeSet = getChangeSets().get(i);
4       if (currentChangeSet.getSequentialNumber() == sequentialNumber) {
5           return currentChangeSet;
6       }
7   }
```

Comment: Does getChangeSets() always return the same list, or will it be created each time you call the method? So please assign the list to a variable before iterating over it.

Comment: For starters, you shouldn't be using `Vector`, for reasons described in its documentation. Generally use `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: Agree completely that Vector is an inappropriate choice - this is very old legacy code, and I'd prefer to make as few changes as possible (the Vector declaration is buried back many layers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better not using indexed iteration:

```
for (ChangeSet currentChangeSet : getChangeSets()) {
  if (currentChangeSet.getSequentialNumber() == sequentialNumber) {
    return currentChangeSet;
  }
}
```

I suspect what is happening in your code is that `getChangeSets()` changes size between invocations, specifically getting smaller. The code above only invokes it once, before the first time the loop executes.

Answer (score 0):

Please assign the changeset to a variable before iteration.

```
List<ChangeSet> list = getChangeSets();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    ChangeSet currentChangeSet = list.get(i);
    if (currentChangeSet.getSequentialNumber() == sequentialNumber) {
        return currentChangeSet;
    }
}
```